# How to create link for instagram

Tags: html, instagram

How to create a link for instagram with similar functionality "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=sometext"?

Comment: Tell your problem more briefly.

Comment: The +2 on this is in no way suspicious...

Comment: the problem is very clear, you need to create a link for the website when you click on which the instagram app should open, in which a window should automatically open where you need to select the message recipient whose text is in the link itself. I gave as an example a link for whatsapp with similar functionality.

Comment: @Hovsep checkout the rules for SO pls. questions shall be clear and you should show what you've already tried.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hello sir you can use https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api to send dm's to your user.  It's in nodejs

Idk in what  language you'll try to use to do this, in the link I provided it's done in node, altho you can read it to grasp an example of what you might be trying to do.